# How to change a specific Icon color in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change an IconButton's color when the user clicks on it, I've tried setting a state when user clicks on it, but the problem is that every Icon in the page changes color i want this to happen to the buttons that user clicks not all of them, these icons are for social media posts so i cant define a variable.

```
                     Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 10.0),
                  child : Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [


                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.favorite_border,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            size : 25.0
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {

                        },
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '29k',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color : Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.question_answer,
                            color: _likeButtonColor,
                            size : 25.0
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print(games[index]['posts']);
                          setState(() {
                            _likeButtonColor = Colors.red;
                          });
                        },

                      ),
                      Text(
                        '1312',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color : Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                        ),
                      )


                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have tried so I can help? It will be hard to render help from here @imcouri

Comment: do you mean the list view that the icon is nested in it? or the whole page?

Comment: If you can post the whole page. It will help in giving appropriate help @imcouri

Comment: are you sure because it's 1400 lines long?

Comment: Extract the main part where you are having errors/issues. It is hard to give help with the little snippet you posted @imcouri

Comment: i edited my code, i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using same variable for all IconButton widget's color property.

You have to create a list which hold the value of color for each items let me show you with example.

```
class Delet2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Delet2State createState() => _Delet2State();
}

class _Delet2State extends State<Delet2> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<Color> _colors = [];

  getdatafromserver() async {
    await Future.delayed(
        Duration(seconds: 2)); //this show you are fetching data from server
    _colors =
        List.generate(10, (index) => Colors.amber); // here 10 is items.length
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getdatafromserver();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _colors.length ?? 0,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.question_answer,
                  color: _colors[index], size: 25.0),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _colors[index] = Colors.red;
                });
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i dont know how many posts are going to be in this page so i cant make a list for them

Comment: how you calculate how much widget you have show? can you add that part  of code where you get some idea that i want to show that much  IconButton?

Comment: i use a list view builder and i show these buttons with each post, could you please be a little more specific about what are you looking for?

Comment: i just want to know how much buttons you want to show. i understand that in stating you don't have any count but in some place you have count that you want to show this number of buttons on screen. so i want to know where and how you calculate how much buttons you want to show?

Comment: itemCount: items.length, itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index), items is an array that contains the data that i get from the server and i calculate the number by using items.length in my list view builder

Comment: @imcouri i updated my answer. i hope now you will get idea how to do in your case.